# Error: "TypeError: hidden_tag() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' " in Flask, python

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

I've been creating a forum based learning system, similar to stack overflow for an assessed project.  I'm fairly new to flask, however I believe i have a decent understanding of python.  I have been following [Corey Schafer's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwZwr5Tvyxo&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH) Flask tutorials and adapting them to my project.  Whenever I try to access the page called 'adduser', a webpage with a form for adding users, I get the error:

`"TypeError: hidden_tag() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'".`

I have no idea what this means or how to even attempt to fix it.
I assumed that I might find the fix in the HTML for the 'adduser' page, and after removing the `'{{ form.hidden_tag() }}'` tag, I got a different error, which leads me to believe that the error is has something to do with the `'forms.py'` file and the `'addUser.html'` file.

***forms.py***

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo, ValidationError
from itroom.models import User

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email',validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Login')

class AddUserForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email',validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Add User')

    def validate_email(self,email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(userEmail=email.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError('Email already exists in database.')
```

***addUser.html***

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block content %}

  <div class="center2" style="border-color: white;">
  <h2 align="center" style="padding: 2.5%;"></h2>
    <h1>Add a User</h1>   
      <form method="POST" action="">
         {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div class="form-group">
          {{form.email.label}}
          {% if form.email.errors %}
          {{form.email(size=30, class="form-control is-invalid")}}
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          {% for error in form.email.errors %}
          <span>{{ error }}</span>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
          {% else %}
          {{form.email(size=30, class="form-control")}}
          {% endif %}
        </div>
          {{form.password.label}} <br>
          {{form.password(size=30)}}

          {{form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info")}} <br>

      </form>
      </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I also thought the routes file may be helpful aswell.

***routes.py***

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from itroom import app, db, bcrypt
from itroom.forms import LoginForm, AddUserForm
from itroom.models import User, Post
from flask_login import login_user

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")     #defines the HTML loaded for /home
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', title='Home')


@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])       #defines the HTML loaded for /login
def login():
    form = LoginForm('')
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.userEmail.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.userPassword, form.password):
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unsucessful, Please check email and password') 
    return render_template('login.html',form=form, title='Login')

@app.route("/adduser", methods=['GET', 'POST'])       #defines the HTML loaded for /adduser
def addUser():
    form = AddUserForm('/login')
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode ('utf-8')
        user = User(userEmail=form.email.data, userPassword = hashed_password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        temptext = ("Account created for '", form.email.data, "'." )
        flash(temptext)

    else:
        flash('Account not created')
    return render_template('addUser.html', title='Admin', form=AddUserForm)
```

Thank you in advance for anyone who tries to help!

Comment: [Corey Schafer](https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer) shares his code on his [github](https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Python/Flask_Blog) page, did you try comparing your code with his

Comment: Yes, after every error I run into I check my code against his.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The TypeError is saying that self was not passed to the hidden_tag method. You can have this error if you do the following by accident:

```py
class A:
    def test(self):
        print('test')

A.test() # TypeError: test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
A().test() # prints test
```

So this means that you are calling the method with a class object.

In your routes, you have the following rule where you pass a class to your page, but you likely wanted to return your actual form object. So you have to change

```py
return render_template('addUser.html', title='Admin', form=AddUserForm)
```

to

```py
form = AddUserForm('/login')
...
return render_template('addUser.html', title='Admin', form=form)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This error message is a bit confusing, this is exactly what cause the issue

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to call the form at the end of your last return statement.

current code

```
else:
    flash('Account not created')
return render_template('addUser.html', title='Admin', form=AddUserForm)
```

fixed code

```
else:
    flash('Account not created')
return render_template('addUser.html', title='Admin', form=AddUserForm())
```

or since you already specified that

```
form = AddUserForm('/login')
```

just specify it at the end like you did in other routes

```
return render_template('addUser.html', title='Admin', form=form)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, me following the same tutorial from  Corey Schafer's flask. The main reason why you are getting `TypeError: hidden_tag() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self` is because of the route page form [the bracket needs to prevent the error and to signify the tag function()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBIkq.jpg)

Comment: Please include code in the answer, not in an image.

Comment: I faced this error, and this answer helped me to fix. Kudos!!!!
Wrong: 
    form = CandidateForm
Correct 
     form = CandidateForm()